# Singleton with ObservableCollection as a member

Tags: c#, singleton

i have this `ObservableCollection<MyData> list` that i want to insert inside my Singleton:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();
   public static ObservableCollection<MyData> list {get; set;}

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null)
               {
                  instance = new Singleton();
                  list = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
               }
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Is this the This is the right way to define it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is. If the `ObservableCollection` should be a member of the `Singleton` class, instantiate it in the `Singleton's` private constructor. If it shouldn't, I don't see why you doing it this way. What happens when you call `Singleton.list` BEFORE `Singleton.Instance`? `NullReferenceException`. And since its setter is public, it can be set from outside as well which is probably not what you want.

I would modify your code like this:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   public ObservableCollection<MyData> list {get; private set;}

   private Singleton() {
       list = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
   }

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null)
               {
                  instance = new Singleton();
               }
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```